# Wget -i gives no output or results

Tags: csv, wget, apache-zeppelin

I'm learning data analysis in Zeppelin, I'm a mechanical engineer so this is outside my expertise.

I am trying to download two csv files using a file that contains the urls, test2.txt. When I run it I get no output, but no error message either.  I've included a link to a screenshot showing my code and the results.

When I go into Ambari Sandbox I cannot find any files created. I'm assuming the directory the file is in is where the csv files will be downloaded too.  I've tried using -P as well with no luck. I've checked in man wget but it did not help.

So I have several questions:

1. How do I show the output from running wget?
2. Where is the default directory that wget stores files?
3. Do I need additional data in the file other than just the URLs?
   [Screenshot: Code and Output for %sh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hp3Z.png)
   Thanks for any and all help.

`%sh`
 wget -i /tmp/test2.txt

Comment: 1) AFAIK, `wget` doesn't show any output, it either downloads the files or throws exceptions if there were any errors. 2) `wget` downloads into the current directory. 3) No, just the URL is sufficient, but you're downloading from a local path, which is not a URL. See this for more info: http://askubuntu.com/questions/530686/is-it-possible-to-use-wget-for-copying-files-in-my-own-system

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I've been able to get my code to work now.  I understand the wget downloads to the current directory but I could not figure out what the directory was.  So I couldn't transfer the test2.txt file over to be used by wget.  I have figured it out thanks to a classmates help.  For anyone else struggling like I was I have the code below.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
%sh

# list the current working directory
pwd # output: home/zeppelin

# make a new folder, created in "tmp" because it is temporary
mkdir -p /home/zeppelin/tmp/Folder_Name

# change directory to new folder
cd /home/zeppelin/tmp/Folder_Name

# transfer the file from the sandbox to the current working directory
hadoop fs -get /tmp/test2.txt /home/zeppelin/tmp/Folder_Name/

# download the URL
wget -i test2.txt
```